# {"error": "Error loading the model"} when using /ml/v1beta1/ml.projects.predict

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, google-apis-explorer

Using the following API Explorer and body,I get the error 
{"error": "Error loading the model"}.  I was going to start using https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/ml/v1beta1/python/latest/ml_v1beta1.projects.html#predict, but would like to verify everything is okay first.

Is there a way to see the actual error?

---

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?authuser=1#p/ml/v1beta1/ml.projects.predict?

POST https://ml.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{project}/models/{model_name}/versions/v1:predict?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "httpBody": {
  "data": "[{\"placeholder_name\": [44, 158, 178, 156, 111, 101, 110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], \"key\": 1}]"
 }
}

200

cache-control:  private
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  53
content-type:  text/html; charset=utf-8
date:  Wed, 22 Feb 2017 05:25:14 GMT
server:  ESF
vary:  Origin, X-Origin, Referer

{"error": "Error loading the model"}
`

Comment: I don't think this is the problem leading to the error you are reporting, but your request itself has several errors, you want:

{ "data": [{"image": [44, 158, 178, 156, 111, 101, 110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], "key": 1}] }

Comment: If email cloudml-feedback@ with your project, model, and version names and approximate date/time you sent the request, we can look into the issue. We'll also investigate why we didn't report the error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the placeholder name "image" for example, was hidden because I was using "< >" notation in stackoverflow.  I also did end up emailing cloudml-feedback@gamil.com.  I look forward to getting this model live.

Answer (score 0):

I added export.meta, export.index and a renamed export.data-00000-of-00001 -> export too cloud storage.

It was an incorrect guess based on the documentation https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/concepts/deployment-overview#deployment_location.

So it looks like you just need the files created by `saver.save(sess, os.path.join(FLAGS.model_dir, 'export'))`